# Nested objects has_one rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, aplicação-web, rails4

Fala galera,

Sou novo em rails e estou tentando fazer um crud com dois objetos , um Project e outro Album. Project has_one Album , como teste cada um só tem um :name como parâmetro , mas não consigo criar um Project com album. Aqui está meu código :

project.rb , album.rb

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_one :album
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :album, allow_destroy: true
end

class Album < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
end
```

ProjectsController.rb

```
def new
 @project = Project.new
 @album = @project.build_album
end

def create
 @project = Project.new
 @album = @project.create_album(params[:album])

respond_to do |format|
  if @project.save
    format.html { redirect_to @project, notice: 'Project was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @project }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @project.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end

def project_params
  params.require(:project).permit(:name, album_attributes: [:name])
end
```

_form.html.erb (project)

```
<%= form_for(@project) do |f| %>
  <% if @project.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
  <h2><%= pluralize(@project.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this project from being saved:</h2>
  <ul>
   <% @project.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
    <li><%= message %></li>
   <% end %>
  </ul>
    </div>
   <% end %>

   <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name, 'Project name: ' %><br>
     <%= f.text_field :name %>
   </div>

 <%= f.fields_for :album do |a| %>
   <div class="field">
     <%= a.label :name, 'Album name' %><br />
     <%= a.text_field :name %>
   </div>
 <% end %>

<div class="actions">
<%= f.submit %>
</div>
```

routes.rb

```
  resources :projects do
   resources :albums
  end
```

Quando crio um project/new ele não está pegando nem o name do project nem do album, mas se crio um album/new ele pega o nome do album.

Estou achando difícil encontrar algo que ajude no controller pra has_one do rails 4.

Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

A ideia de usar o `accepts_nested_attributes_for` é você não precisar criar o álbum explicitamente como você está fazendo no método create.

Basta inicializar o projeto com os parâmetros recebidos do form que o álbum deverá ser criado junto.

```
@project = Project.new(project_params)
```